# Void pointer to integer

Tags: c

I have a method called printNums, where I would like to print integers from 1 - 10. For my assignment, I'm supposed to malloc an int pointer, set it, pass in to my function as a void* point and inside the function, cast it, deference it and print that integer out before each iteration of the counter.

However, I keep getting a segmentation fault after `*((int*)ptr)` and I'm not too sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void* printNums(void *ptr);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  ptr = 0;
  printNums(ptr);

  return 0;

}

void* printNums(void *ptr){

  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++){

    *((int*)ptr) = i; 

    printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr));

  } 

}
```

Comment: `printNums` should return a value (of type `void*`)

Comment: `ptr = 0;` - here you set your newly allocated pointer to `NULL`

Comment: `int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))` allocates memory for exactly one `int`, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: `printNums` prints 10 times the same number. Is this what you intended? Maybe you should tell us what the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning ptr pointer to zero.
change `ptr = 0;` to `*ptr = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the address to zero:

```
ptr = 0;
```

Which means you will definitely (in most environments and operating systems) get a segmentation fault if you try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to set the value pointed by `ptr` to `0` before you can use, so by mistake you made `ptr = 0`

to make all the values pointed by `ptr` to be `0` you need to use `memset`

`memset(ptr,0,sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 0):

> However, I keep getting a segmentation fault after `*((int*)ptr)` and
> I'm not too sure why.

You can try to find out yourself. Programming requires some debugging skills - forums are not the replacement.

```
void* printNums(void *ptr){

  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++){

    printf("%p\n", ptr);
    //*((int*)ptr) = i; 
    //printf("%d\n", *((int*)ptr));
  } 
  return ptr;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EYhGKn

and the output

```
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
(nil)
```

And the answer is obvious: you dereference NULL pointer.

Now you can try to find out why you pass the NULL pointer to the function. As the program is 12 lines long it will not take too much time to discover the line:

```
ptr = 0;
```

Which assigns integer zero to the pointer. So the pointer is now NULL.